# Absolute gridview headers not moving with page action

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

I have created a GridView within my page and I have managed to fix my headers using the

```
top: expression(Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(document.getElementById("GridPanel")).y);
```

in my CSS class.

My issue is that I have also have an Accordion control in my page and every time I open my accordion, my headers don't follow the gridview. They stay at the same exact X,Y within the page.

Is there a way to make the header follow the gridview coordinates ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Now eveything works fine without changing anything. I will investigate this a bit more but it seems that it was a bug from my browser render.